# Next.js 13 Image is not loading when deployed on server (Working fine locally)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next.js14

I am using **next.js `Image` component** for image, by default image is optimized in `Image` component but it is not loading when deployed. when passing `unoptimized` props then image is loading on server.

I **need optimization** as this will help in lazy loading and cache of image.

```js
<Image
    src={LabTestestIcon}
    alt="lab tested verified icon"
    className="h-16 w-16"
    unoptimized
/>
```

The image is located in `public` folder and in `webp` format.